# Was Time invented or discovered?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, time

Me and my elder brother were just talking about some stuff then he asked me a question: Was time invented or discovered and how we define time?

So I googled and it says this:

The measurement of time began with the invention of sundials in ancient Egypt some time prior to 1500 B.C. However, the time the Egyptians measured was not the same as the time today's clocks measure. For the Egyptians, and indeed for a further three millennia, the basic unit of time was the period of daylight

but how you actually define time(I already read that weird definition of time related to caesium) like If I say what is gravity?

it is simply the force with which any physical object that is attracted towards other object is Gravity

My question is that is time physical or hypothetical concept?

I know it's pretty dumb question to ask(after all I'm a 16y/o if that makes sense)

Thank you :)

Comment: Time is experienced. Clocks were invented.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "experienced"???

Comment: We experience the time passing. It is one of the most basic experiences in life.

Comment: if it is a experience then how clocks were designed and why 60seconds in a min why not 50seconds or 100seconds?

Comment: It isn't the concept of time that's defined with respect to Caesium. It's just the second: that *unit* is defined as taking the same *amount* of time as it takes for Caesium to shift between certain states some number of times. It's completely arbitrary; it's just useful to have an objective physical thing such that even if all clocks were to break, we could figure out how long a second is supposed to be by measuring it. (We used seconds before this definition was formalized; the Caesium definition was selected specifically because it works out to the same length we were already using.)

Comment: Division of time in 24 hour and 60 minutes is a historical convention coming from the Sumerians and Babylonians, which is still around with us. Nothing more than that. The 60 system is convenient because oen can easily divide by 2,3,4,12 etc..

Comment: it's all confusing but I have to agree I guess... thank you for your time

Comment: Don't thank us yet; we haven't addressed how time is actually defined yet, and the confusion's going to get worse before it gets better (we're going to have to involve Einstein for the next step), but it'll make sense on the far end. (And surprisingly, the math for the relevant parts of special relativity is quite simple.)  If nobody beats me to it, I'll take a crack at writing a proper answer once I get off work in a few hours (~1.2 * 10^14 Caesium oscillations.)

Comment: Google up the following and start reading.  time is defined so that motion looks simple

Comment: Google is wrong. The measurement of time began much earlier in the form of calendars. And sun dials, for that matter, were almost certainly  just a new instrument to support existing time-keeping customs based on the position of the sun. The actual practice itself surely predates it by millennia.

Comment: Obligatory Doctor Who quote: "*Time is an illusion. Lunchtime doubly so.*"

Comment: Time is a rate of change. If there's no change, then no time has passed. The various conventions used to measure time are just conventions. Similar to inches and centimeters, they are merely different systems of measurement and can be converted into one another mathematically. No one invented length, but meters were invented in order to measure and speak about length.

Comment: @ScottRowe Wasn't that from the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy?

Comment: @Ray quotes are an illusion.

Comment: Time (and Space) is a pure form of intuition (Kant). Additionally, Einstein's spacetime model should not be confused with these forms of intuition. Neither space nor time can be "curved". It's only appearances IN space and time that can be curved and gravitational waves play an interesting role in how it affects this plays out in relation to the objects that are affected by them.

Comment: Time was invented by love and discovered by hate.

Answer (score 2):

> "Was time invented or discovered?"

Concepts with antecedents in reality come in triads:

- the characteristic of reality
- the observations which prompt the conception
- the concept itself, which is like a map constructed out of past observations that is used for predicting future observations on the basis of present observations.

Characteristics of reality are discovered. Observations are experienced. Concepts are invented.

---

> "And how do you define time?" (And what does it have to do with
> 133Cs?)

A **clock** is a machine that repeats the same process over and over again and counts the number of repetitions.

**Time is what a clock measures** by counting repetitions.

A *good* clock is a machine whose number of counts exists in a fixed ratio with the number of counts on other good clocks.

A *really good* clock has a fixed ratio that is measurable with high precision. The more precisely knowable the ratio, the better the clock.

A machine that counts 133Cs transitions happens to be the best clock we know how to make without needing to know any distances or speeds.

Comment: What a clock measures is duration. Time is not only about duration measurement  It encompasses change and flow

Comment: @NikosM. *What a clock measures* is the standard definition in physics. Change with regard to time is the derivative of what something else measures with respect to the differential element of what a clock measures. There's also plenty of change that doesn't involve time at all, for instance, change in altitude with respect to horizontal distance, change in quantity demanded with respect to price, etc, etc. Flux is the amount of what something else measures (e.g. mass) through what a third thing measures (e.g. cross-sectional area) per unit what a clock measures.

Comment: And where exactly did I contradict the definition of physics in my comment? What we measure via clocks (denoted as time coordinate in physics) is duration. Time as the substrate that makes change and duration possible is what I am talking about and not some coordinate on that substrate. In the same sense space is not simply the coordinates on that space.  Derivative measures amount of change and is not the process nor substrate of change itself.

Comment: I may have misidentified your intent. If your meaning is that "time is that characteristic of reality along whose mathematical representation as a geometric dimension clocks measure dispacements" I have no disagreement.

Answer (score 1):

Primal counting system based in 12 numbers, not by 10. people counted by the phalanx bones of the 4 fingers with the help by thumb - 3+3+3+3=12.  12 is more symmetry as Nikos said, it have most of divisors number - 2,3,4,6, and 12. 60 i think is compromise between 12-mal and 10-mal systems.

Chinese tradition system has 12 animals - one animal on 2 day/night hours. 10 is not devide by 4, so you cant get times like: morning, day, evening, night. Also 12 months(13 was moon months), and 12 years in circle. Also 4 classic seasons.

But also there was 5 elements: water, fire, earth, air, metal. That is why you get number 5. At the hands there is not "5" fingers - there is 4 and 1...

So, that mean how you should count them, as all similar, or 4 to 1.

But the main thing was the time was a circle - an hour, a day, a month(sun or moon nvm), a year. And nowaday the time is a line. The line time was invented at ~ 16 century, time as a moment, time with past and future.

So you have 2 kind of times - circle one (with a symmetry, 12-mal usually), and line one(with past, and future). First was "discovered", and second was invented, for some reason.

What was the reason it is another big question.

Comment: But what about that Second hand? Which is the first?

Comment: @ScottRowe which was the first of what)?

Comment: The first of the hands.

Comment: @ScottRowe i thought about your question), if you mean the clock hand, i think sun hand  was first, that mean (half)day time~12+3-4~hour depends on region latitude. Also sun clock not need to know the sun time +/-, and sand clocks was appeared and 1~ century before oe. But also we need to take into account the year clocks, so your question should be: which was first the day hand or the year hand)

Comment: I always thought the analemma was fascinating.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to ask your elder brother what he thinks is the answer to the question 'Was space discovered or invented?', since according to modern physics time is one of four dimensions of 'spacetime'.

Time was neither invented nor discovered. As with the other three dimensions of space, we are born into it become aware of it as soon as we grow old enough.

We do not define time in terms of the transitions within Caesium- we define a second that way, which is a measure of time, not time itself.

Comment: I told him the same thing but he said "that gravity was always there and you can actually define the term 'gravity' but how do you define time?" i don't know maybe he's trying to play word games kinda thing cause I'm always curious about space and related stuff(basically physics I guess) so he asks these type of weird questions sometimes

Comment: Dazzle your brother with your brilliant insights. Tell him that time, like space and mass are fundamental dimensions of nature, in terms of which we can define other derived quantities such as forces. Gravity is a consequence of the curvature of space and time.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of time is that it's the concept that lets us say what order things happened in, and "how long" it was between them. It's easy to think about this intuitively, but
it turns out there are some subtleties that we didn't really think about until the early 20th century, with the development of Special Relativity. Indeed, the question of what exactly time *is* is more or less what led Einstein to start thinking in that direction. (The other part of the question was why Maxwell's equations predicted a constant speed of light).

Let's look at what the concept of time allows us to say about events. Suppose we have events `x` and `y`.
Time is a method of associating each event `z` with some number `t(z)` such that we're able to answer the following questions:

- Does x happen at the same time as y? (t(x) = t(y))
- Does x happen before y?  (t(x) < t(x))
- If y happened after x, how *long* after x did it happen? (t(y) - t(x))

We'll examine these using one of Einstein's thought experiments.
Suppose we have a platform, a train track running parallel to it, and a moving train.
Alice (A) is standing on the platform, exactly halfway between the points labeled x and y. Bob (B) is standing on the train.

```
======B======     train
x     A     y     platform
```

Now suppose that each side of the platform is struck by a bolt of lightning.  Did the lightning strikes happen at the same time? Or rather, *how do we define simultaneity such that we can answer that question?* For Alice, we have a practical answer: the distance from her to each strike is the same, so the strikes were simultaneous if (and only if) the light from each reaches her at the same time.
So, that's the first question answered. The second question is straightforward, too: if the light from x gets there first, that lightning strike happened earlier.

To answer our third question, we're going to give Alice a "light clock", which is a pair of mirrors, 30cm apart, with a single photon of light bouncing between them. Every time the photon hits one of the mirrors, the clock beeps (it's a lot easier to build things like that in thought experiments than in the real world). We're going to *define* a nanosecond as the length of time between each beep.

There's some weirdness going on in that definition, so let's look at it more closely: normally, speed is defined as the distance traveled per second. So the speed of light would be some value `c` that measures how far light travels in a certain amount of time, c = x meters per t seconds. But here, we're doing things in reverse. We *define* light speed to be 300 million m/s (I rounded up a bit). We can then *measure* the length between the two mirrors, and finally *compute* the time it takes for light to move between the mirrors: 30cm / c = 1 nanosecond.
(If that last paragraph wasn't clear, take some time to think about it (and/or ask clarifying questions in the comments). It requires some sideways thinking, but is an important concept.)

Now that we have the light clock, we can use it to answer our third question: when the light from the first strike arrives, count the beeps until the light from the second one gets there.

Things get a bit<sup>1</sup> more complicated when we consider things from both Alice's and Bob's reference frames (Inertial reference frames are coordinate systems that are moving at a constant speed relative to each other. The train and platform are the reference frames in this example).
We've already worked out everything from Alice's reference frame, and she says that that lightning hit both x and y at time 0.
Coincidentally, time 0 was also the exact instant that Bob (on the train) passed Alice.
So let's look at things from Bob's reference frame. The points x and y on the platform correspond to points x' and y' on the train (since we only care about the direction the train is moving in. Alternately, it's an unusually wide lightning bolt that hits both x and x').

```
x'=====B=====y'
x      A     y
```

But Bob is moving towards y and away from x. The light from x has farther to go, so Bob sees that light from y *first*, which means that by our definition of simultaneity, the lightning bolts were *not* simultaneous from Bob's reference frame. (The light from the front end of the train where the lightning hit is moving towards Bob at the same speed as the light from the lightning himself, so even though the point y' is staying the same distance from Bob, the *light* from point y' at the moment of the lightning strike isn't, so Bob sees the lightning strike the same point on the train that Alice saw.)
So Alice says the lightning bolts were simultaneous in her reference frame (platform), Bob says they weren't in his (train), and neither is wrong<sup>2</sup> (although Bob can compute what Alice sees and vice versa). "Relativity of Simultaneity" is the phrase to search for if you want more details.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a bit<sup>1</sup> of an understatement.

<sup>2</sup> Also, the train shrinks and both Alice and Bob see the other's clock moving slower than their own. The universe is weird sometimes.

<sup>3</sup> https://physics.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask than here, if you have specific questions.

Comment: yeah I first asked that question there but they said "it is more relevant here(philosophy stack exxchange) " and they closed it :(

Comment: One can argue that SR does not describe time *per se*, but the behavior of  clocks (and measuring rods) as per Einstein's original 1905 paper

Comment: @Shardul Yeah, this question would be a bit open-ended for them. But if you had more specific questions like "What exactly determines if Alice and Bob are in different reference frames?" or "How can Alice calculate how much slower Bob sees her clock running?", that'd be where you'd find the relevant expertise.

Comment: @NikosM. Einstein framed the question in terms of clocks and measuring rods specifically because existing intuitions of what time was were too vague and handwavy to permit making specific predictions. If we try to answer questions like "Did those lightning bolts happen at the same time?" using the intuition, we always end up with some sort of circular reasoning. Defining time as "the thing that (light) clocks measure" might be psychologically unsatisfying, but it's the definition that lets us make those predictions precisely without circular reasoning or contradiction.

Comment: @Ray i don't see a difference in your comment with my comment. Again you talk about clocks and their measurements not about time *per se*. Time is not only about duration or simultaneity, but most importantly about change and flow. SR is not about that  But the 2nd law is related to that.

Comment: @NikosM. I'm saying that the stuff with clocks and their measurement *is* time per se, because that's the definition that 1) is internally consistent and 2) lets us make predictions that agree with experiment. A def'n that doesn't is useless. Once you have the function f(x)->t, you can calculate change *with respect to time* (by taking a derivative if f is a continuous function, or by describing a sequence if it isn't). You can also calculate change with respect to other things, e.g. position, so change isn't just about time. Not sure what you mean by flow; can you define it mathematically?

Comment: @Ray what you call time is only duration measurement, which is a feature of time, not time per se. Time is about things flowing, changing, passing. The derivative measures the amount of change, it is not change itself, nor the cause of change. I hope these distinctions are clear. It is like confusing space with coordinates on that space and amount of change with the process of change

Comment: ,@Ray in other words, time is not simply duration but the substrate that makes duration and change possible. In the same sense space is not distance but the substrate which makes distance, width,etc possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144475/discussion-between-ray-and-nikos-m).